# I want to draw a pipeline image like draw a line that follow the mouse cursor

Tags: html, canvas, cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw a pipeline image (below) like draw a line, that follow the mouse cursor. When I press down the left button,and move the mouse cursor,the pipeline image draw to the cursor position （Like bessel curve)
. How can I do that? Thank you!

[image: pipeline image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here’s an example of how to define a “tube” given some mouse points.**

The red points connected by red lines represent your mouse points.

The green & blue lines are calculated to be parallel to the red mouse line with an offset of 15 pixels.

The green & blue lines form the outside of your tube.

[image]

I'll help you with the math, but styling your tube is up to you.

Requires some trigonometry...ready?

Given that your mouse travels along a polyline (a series of points connected by line segments). Your mouse points are the red line in the illustration.

At each point, calculate 2 points perpendicular to that point and on either side of that point.
When you connect these perpendicular points, they become the sides of your "tube". These are the green & blue lines on either side of the mouse line.

How:

Use Math.atan2 to calculate the angle of slope between [x1,y1] and [x2,y2].

```
var dx=x2-x1;
var dy=y2-y1;
var originalAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
```

Use Math.cos/Math.sin to find 2 points perpendicular to [x1,y1]

```
// a perpendicular angle is always 90 degrees different
// from the angle of the original line.
// (90 degrees == Math.PI/2 radians)
// let's subtract 90 degrees 

var perpendicularAngle=originalAngle-Math.PI/2;

// let's get a perpendicular point that's 
// 15 pixels away from [x1,y1]

var offsetLength=15;

// use cosine and sine to calculate that perpendicular point

var perpX1=x1+offsetLength*Math.cos(perpendicularAngle);
var perpY1=y1+offsetLength*Math.sin(perpendicularAngle);

// repeat to get the opposite perpendicular point
// This time add 90 degrees to the original angle.

var perpendicularAngle=originalAngle+Math.PI/2;
var perpX2=x1+offsetLength*Math.cos(perpendicularAngle);
var perpY2=y1+offsetLength*Math.sin(perpendicularAngle);
```

One edge issue you must work around: If the angle of slope is either horizontal or vertical, the cosine/sine calculation won't work.  Instead, just add/subtract the offset length to the point.

The math part is done!

Now just style the data-points as you desire. Maybe connect the perpendicular points on each side of the mouse line to form the sides of your tube.  Apply some semi-transparent fill to allow the background to show through.  Whatever your design requires.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for your solution。it seems a good way for me. I'll try it.^_^